# I have a question about properties of series.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers.

Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n $ converges, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}x_k=0.$

This is what I have done. We have by the Cauchy Criterion, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N \ \implies |\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}x_k|<\epsilon.$ Taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we get the desired result.

Are there any problems with my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ be the partial sums.  If the series is convergent, then $S_n\to s$, and for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N>0$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $\vert S_n-s\vert < \epsilon$.  Since $s=\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ we have $$\vert s-S_n\vert =\left\vert\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k - \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right\vert= \left\vert\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x_k\right\vert < \epsilon.$$

Since this is true for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$, the sums must converge to zero.

EDIT: you can claim at the end that the series is convergent to zero so the index does not matter, or you can write it this way:

For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N>0$ such that $n-1\ge N$ implies $\vert S_{n-1}-s\vert < \epsilon$.  Since $s=\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ we have $$\vert s-S_{n-1}\vert =\left\vert\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k \right\vert= \left\vert\sum_{k=n}^\infty x_k\right\vert < \epsilon.$$

Which way is better is up to you (and your prof).

Comment: Is there something wrong with the way I did it?

Comment: I think so.  How does taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ make the sums smaller?

Comment: But we both arrive at |sum x_k | < epsilon, the only difference is you have n+1 and I have n.

Comment: @tmpys But the issue is arriving there, and the steps in your proof don't make it obvious how you do so.

Comment: I agree, you should arrive at $n$ not $n+1$, I can edit my answer if necessary.  The important detail is the last line.  In your proof you say "take the limit as $n\to\infty$", which doesn't achieve the required result.  As a grader, I would also want to see a little more detail than you showed, which I have included in my version of the proof.

Comment: well I dont see anything about lim as n goes to infinity in your version and the question is about such a limit. Maybe im just confused.

Comment: never-mind, I see now. thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I have one more question, how could we make it n and not n+1, it seems to me that the way you wrote it is fine. Does that even matter since we are going to infinity?

Comment: ok so since s_n converges to s, surely s_n-1 converges to s, then replacing n with n-1 resolves the problem? @Jeff Snider ?

Comment: great thanks. you made many a lightbulb come on.